# Diophantine equation $x^4-x^2y^2-y^4=a^4+a^2b^2-b^4$

Tags: number-theory

Let $A$ be the set of pairs of coprime positive integers $(a, b)$, for which diophantine equation $x^4-x^2y^2-y^4=a^4+a^2b^2-b^4$ has solutions in the positive integers $(x,y)$.

a) Is $A$ finite or infinite?

b) Does this equation have solutions in case $a=b=1$?

**My work**

I've posted similar question about equation [$x^2-xy-y^2=a^2+ab-b^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3280976/diophantine-equation-x2-xy-y2-a2ab-b2)

Also, in section b) I've found 2 solutions - $(1,0)$, $(-1,0)$ (using Wolfram Mathemathica), but neither of them are in the positive integers and I do not know how to show the lack of other solutions

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jbuztako2u

Comment: @Mason In your graph $x = a$ and $y = b$, but it can be false

Answer (score 2):

COMMENT.-Since $x^4\equiv1\text{ or }0\pmod{16}$ we reduce the values, modulo $16$, of $$n=x^4-x^2y^2-y^4$$  to the following six values $n=0,1,3,5,9,15$ modulo $16$ (ten values are discarded as impossible).

►$a$ and $b$ even:$\quad a^4+a^2b^2-b^4\equiv0\pmod{16}\quad n\equiv0\pmod{16}$.

►$a$ and $b$ odd:$\quad a^4+a^2b^2-b^4\equiv a^2b^2\pmod{16}\quad n\equiv1\text{ or }9\pmod{16}$

►$a$ even and $b$ odd:$\quad n\equiv3\text{ or }15\pmod{16}$.

►$a$ odd and $b$ even $\quad n\equiv1\text{ or }5\pmod{16}$.

Comment: But if $a$ and $b$ are even, then they are not coprime, so we can put this case aside

Comment: @Назавр You are right although I put it anyway. Thanks you. By the way It is known that $x^4\pm y^4=z^2$ has not non-trivial solutions which could help something maybe. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Similar equations have been solved [here](https://gaurish4math.files.wordpress.com/2015/12/diophantine-equations-gaurish-rev4.pdf), in Theorem $2.4.2$ on page $72$. More precisely, the equations
$$
x^4-x^2y^2+y^4=z^2,\; x^4+x^2y^2+y^4=z^2
$$
have been solved in integers. I think the methods are also useful to solve
$$
x^4-x^2y^2-y^4=1
$$
in integers.

Comment: This theorem gives solutions to the equation $x^4-x^2y^2+y^4=1$, not $x^4-x^2y^2-y^4=1$

Comment: Yes, but it should work similarly.